# How to roll camera with a button while using TrackballControls in ThreeJS without conflicts?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I use `ThreeJS`, I want to roll the camera through a button. I wrote the following code:

```js
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...)

function roll(angle) {
    const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const lookat = this.camera.position.clone().negate().normalize();
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(lookat, THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(angle));
    camera.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
}
```

However, when I use `TrackballControls` at the same time, the camera cannot be rotated by my button, for example:

```js
controls = new TrackballControls(...)

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    this.controls.update();
    ...
}
```

If I comment out `this.controls.update()`, the camera can rotate, but `TrackballControls` will not work. Further searching found that `update()` resets the rotation operation.

I have tried the following: 1) Disable `this.controls` when `rotate`; 2) Destroy `controls` at the beginning of `rotate` and recreate it at the end. But these methods do not work.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `TrackballControls` does not support FOV operations well, just change it to ArcballControls and I can freely rotate on the z-axis. [The official document](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=control#examples/en/controls/ArcballControls) says:

> Moreover Arcball controls allow FOV manipulation (in a vertigo-style method) and z-rotation.